# Javascript QR code generator

Tags: javascript, qr-code

Hi am a beginner in PHP and learning to write small scripts. I use ubuntu OS and installed PHP on it.I wrote a simple `echo()` in a PHP file and stated running it. I came to know from tutorials that I should execute it at localhost. I did the same, but my file isn't executing and it's showing the error 404 - file not found. What might have happened?

**My PHP code**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo "learning php";
    echo"<br>";
    echo "I am trying \"quotations\"";
    //just checking how comments work?
?>
</body>
</html>
```

- executed at `http://localhost/learn.php`

o/p: Not found the requested url `/learn.php` was not found on server apache/2.2.22 ubuntu server at localhost port 80.

I'm beginner to Javascript programming, and I have searched for javascript QR generator code for desktop application "No need for web", and I found this on this site:
http://d-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/qrcode/js/qrcode.js

then I added a function to call the functions in order to generate the QR image

```
var create_qrcode = function(text, typeNumber, errorCorrectLevel, table) {
  var qr = qrcode(typeNumber || 4, errorCorrectLevel || 'M');
  qr.addData(text);
  qr.make();
  //return qr.createTableTag();
  return qr.createImgTag();
}

var t  = create_qrcode("Test QR generate!",4,'M');
```

then I took the return value and echo it

```
WScript.Echo(t);
```

then there is a t.gif image is created but I couldn't be able to open it
and I'm little confused about echoing the image like this 
and Also, I can't find out where should the generated QR image is saved if I didn't call `Wscript.Echo(t)`? and what is its name ?

So please , if any can help me and trace the given code or try to tell me a hint how should I debug this, I'll be grateful .

Answer (score 0):

In response to the ***JavaScript*** QR code bit,

1. Your QR code is not being saved, it's just stored in memory
2. The format it is in is, the string representation of an HTML `<img>` where the QR code is set as the *src*, a *dataURI*.
3. Your [**linked script**](http://d-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/qrcode/js/qrcode.js) doesn't seem to provide methods for directly accessing this *dataURI*, a *Blob*, or anything useful beyond the `<img>` string.

What is it you actually want to do with the QR code? If you just want to display it, append it to the document somehow; [**for example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cT2hy/) (assuming client side, if you're doing this in node.js then you'll have to use different methods)

```
function createNodeQR(text, typeNumber, errorCorrectLevel, table) {
    var qr = qrcode(typeNumber || 4, errorCorrectLevel || 'M'),
        parent = document.createElement('span'), // enable .innerHTML
        img;
    qr.addData(text);
    qr.make();
    parent.innerHTML = qr.createImgTag(); // make client's browser parse
    img = parent.firstChild; // find it
    parent.removeChild(img); // orphan it (optional)
    return img;
}
var t  = createNodeQR("Test QR generate!",4,'M');
console.log(t);     // image node
console.log(t.src); // data uri only
```

Still remember that this is only in memory. If you want to save a resource through *JavaScript*, you're limited in what you can do, it is easiest to make the client do it themselves.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your reply

I don't want to use it as it's client and server application 
all what I want is just generate the QR image and save it in image extension (.png , . jpg .. etc) 
so I can use this image in my desktop application

Comment: I can say finally I solved my problem 
I found a post in other forum and it matches my need 
in order any one has the same need here is the link
http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=62408&p=276665#p276665